# como centrar icono dentro de una etiqueta li - a

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

no sé que hago mal, pero no logro centrar un icono de font awesome, ya intenté con `width: 50%` y `margin: auto` pero no quiere funcionar, también intenté con `text-center` y tampoco, pido de su amable ayuda.

Ejemplo:

```css
.social-twitter {
  background-color: #0084ff;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.social-twitter a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="mt-4 mb-3 p-3 bg_white shadow-sm">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    
    <li class="nav-item social-twitter mr-1">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item social-youtube mr-1">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item social-facebook">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema proviene de la clase `.nav-link`, añade un padding al elemento por lo que no cabe el icono.

Prueba a cambiar el estilo del enlace a esto y me dices si te funciona!!

```
.social-twitter a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado :)

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo únicamente **margin: 0 auto** a **.social-twitter** funciona.

El estilo quedaría así:

```
.social-twitter{background-color: #0084ff; height: 45px; width: 45px; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 auto;} 
.social-twitter a{color:#fff; font-size:20px;}
```

Comment: no funciona, empuja todo el contenido a la derecha